# Additional partitions in buildroot

Tags: partitioning, partition, buildroot

I'd like to know if it's possible to add more partitions in the partition table, and how.
I've tested to change the `genimage.cfg` but it seems that `support/scripts/genimage.sh` doesn't create it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Changing the genimage.cfg is indeed the way to go. If that didn't work, you probably did something wrong there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `genimage.cfg` script is the right way to go.

If it does not work, you might be modifying the wrong config file; `genimage` is usually invoked by a script specified as 
Make sure to modify the right config file however, the one used by the script defined in the `BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT` option, under `System configuration-> Custom scripts to run after creating filesystem images` in `menuconfig`.

For example, I modified mine (specifically `boards/raspberrypi3-64/genimage-raspberrypi3-64.cfg` to accomodate for an extra ext4 partition.

```
image boot.vfat {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  vfat {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    files = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      "bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb",                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      "bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb",                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      "bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb",                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      "rpi-firmware/bootcode.bin",                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      "rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt",                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      "rpi-firmware/config.txt",                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      "rpi-firmware/fixup.dat",                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      "rpi-firmware/start.elf",                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      "rpi-firmware/overlays",                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      "Image"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  size = 32M                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

image sdcard.img {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  hdimage {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  partition boot {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    partition-type = 0xC                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    bootable = "true"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    image = "boot.vfat"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  partition rootfs {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    partition-type = 0x83                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    image = "rootfs.ext4"                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  partition log {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    partition-type = 0x83                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    image = "log.ext4"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Comment: genimage documentation [here](https://github.com/pengutronix/genimage)