# Multiple partitions in buildroot?

Tags: embedded-linux, partitioning, buildroot

Let's discuss a very common case in building up a system image, in which, we need our rootfs as `SquashFs` to be read-only indeed, and another `ext4` partition(let's say `home`) for general read-write storage.

The system image layout(`genimage.cfg`) looks like this in a buildroot environment:

```
image sdcard.img {
  hdimage {}

  partition boot {
    partition-type = 0xC
    bootable = "true"
    image = "boot.vfat"
  }

  partition rootfs {
    partition-type = 0x83
    image = "rootfs.squashfs"
  }

  partition home {
    partition-type = 0x83
    image = "home.ext4"
  }
}

image boot.vfat {
  vfat {
    files = {
      "bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb",
      "rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt",
      "rpi-firmware/config.txt",
      "rpi-firmware/fixup4.dat",
      "rpi-firmware/start4.elf",
      "rpi-firmware/overlays",
      "zImage"
    }
  }
  size = 16M
}

image home.ext4 {
  name = "home"
  mountpoint = "/home"
  ext4 {}
  size = 32M
}
```

But in final stage of creating image, we end up with an error:

```sh
>>   Executing post-image script ~/rpi4/post-image.sh
INFO: cmd: "mkdir -p "/home/iman/rpi4/genimage.tmp"" (stderr+stdout):
INFO: cmd: "rm -rf "/home/iman/rpi4/genimage.tmp"/*" (stderr+stdout):
DEBUG: hdimage(sdcard.img): adding implicit file rule for 'rootfs.squashfs'
DEBUG: vfat(boot.vfat): adding implicit file rule for 'bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb'
DEBUG: vfat(boot.vfat): adding implicit file rule for 'rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt'
DEBUG: vfat(boot.vfat): adding implicit file rule for 'rpi-firmware/config.txt'
DEBUG: vfat(boot.vfat): adding implicit file rule for 'rpi-firmware/fixup4.dat'
DEBUG: vfat(boot.vfat): adding implicit file rule for 'rpi-firmware/start4.elf'
DEBUG: vfat(boot.vfat): adding implicit file rule for 'rpi-firmware/overlays'
DEBUG: vfat(boot.vfat): adding implicit file rule for 'zImage'
INFO: cmd: "mkdir -p "/home/iman/rpi4/genimage.tmp"" (stderr+stdout):
INFO: cmd: "cp -a "/tmp/tmp.dMfSigyUwW" "/home/iman/rpi4/genimage.tmp/root"" (stderr+stdout):
INFO: cmd: "mv "/home/iman/rpi4/genimage.tmp/root/home" "/home/iman/rpi4/genimage.tmp/home"" (stderr+stdout):
mv: cannot stat '/home/iman/rpi4/genimage.tmp/root/home': No such file or directory
Makefile:809: recipe for target 'target-post-image' failed
make[1]: *** [target-post-image] Error 1
Makefile:84: recipe for target '_all' failed
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

What other steps should be taken care of?

Or in more general, what is the way to creating + mounting new partition in buildroot?

Answer (score 4):

If you want an empty `/home` directory then you should *not* use the `mountpoint` keyword:

```
image home.ext4 {
  name = "home"
  ext4 {}
  size = 32M
}
```

The `mountpoint` keyword does *not* tell where the partition will be mounted. See [The genimage docs](https://github.com/pengutronix/genimage/blob/master/README.rst#the-image-section) for an explanation of what it does.

If you want to mount your partition from your rootfs then you can add it to `/etc/fstab`, perhaps in a rootfs overlay ([BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#rootfs-custom)). genimage has no control on what will be actually mounted.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of examples in [test/](https://github.com/pengutronix/genimage/tree/master/test) folder. For example it's about How add empty [partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698152/additional-partitions-in-buildroot) in your image:

```
image test.hdimage {
    hdimage {
        align = 1M
        disk-signature = 0x12345678
    }
    partition part1 {
        image = "part2.img"
        size = 5k
        partition-type = 0x83
    }
    partition extraimage {
        image = "diskEmpty.ext2"
    }
}

image diskEmpty.ext2 {
        size = 10M //space for user, real space = (space for user + space for filesystem) > 10M
        empty = true
        temporary = true
        ext2 {
            label = "my_empty"
            use-mke2fs = true
        }
}
```